# How do I skip one method to another when running the whole class?

Tags: java, android, ui-automation

I tried to test several tests under one class,for example there are three tests I need to test,
`testA()`、`testB()`、`testC()`

The problem is that is there any code that I can skip `testA()` and continue to `testB()` if `testA()` went wrong during testing?

I tried `system.exit(1)` but it will stop the whole class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
try{
   //if there is any error here, it will skip and will be caught by the catch block
   testA()
} catch (Exception e){
   //handle your exception here
   testB()    
}
```

Check out: `Try-catch` for exception handling

Comment: Hi,is there any possible to make `testA()` test result fail(show error) and continued to `testB()` ?
cause when I use return it shows test pass.

Comment: Ya, use the "try-catch" statement above... if there is an error in testA(), it will goes to testB(), else if testA() passed, it will go through testA() and ignore testB()